# Button not clickable on scrollview Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my layout file code

Everything is working fine but Button in not clickable.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/maps"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/custom_actionbar" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/pf_color"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="TRACK"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help related this problem. I am thankful to you.
I am not able to sort out what is the actual problem. I tried android:clickable="true" but still same problem
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you set clicklistener on this button in java file

Comment: could we have the activity please?

Comment: after adding onCLickListener it is working but not acting as button

Comment: no ripple effect no feel of button it is acting as text clickabe

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to set onCLickListener

does ur main class implements onClickListener if so do:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case: R.id.YOURBUTTON:
             //do ur stuff
        break;
        default:
            //todo when the screen is touched
        break;
    }
}
```

I couldnt find your buttons ID btw thats why I called it YOURBUTTON

Comment: after adding onCLickListener it is working but not acting as button.no ripple effect no feel of button it is acting as text clickabe

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line into your button in the XML:

`android:onClick="myClickFunction"`

So it would be:

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/pf_color"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="TRACK"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="myClickFunction" />
```

And then put this in your activity:

```
public void myClickFunction(View v) {
    // do stuff when clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use latest support library, `com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0`? I think it's a bug because i have the same problem..

Comment: I have the same problem with buttons, i discovered it 3 days ago. I looked for any kind of bug for latest library, but i didn't find anything. It's annoying..